# Enterprise Task Management Bug system

Tags: issue-tracking

I'm not sure of SO is the correct place to be asking this, but since the majority of the users here work with a task management system, this may be a great place to ask this question.

My company has a need to do workflow and management. So lets say a new person gets hired... HR should be able to create a ticket, and it dispatches a task to the admin to get a key created, a task to IT to get the computer setup, a task to payroll, etc etc.

I tried retrofitting solutions like Trac/Redmine, but unfortunately they don't support the concept of having a set of tasks assigned to actors when a certain type of ticket is created.

Has anyone used something like this? Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A task management system is not what you think it is. Issue management usually refers to tracking work on a project.

For example, you have multiple employees, each with a specific role. You use an issue management system to track the work for each user and for the entire project.

What you are asking for doesn't exist. And the reason is: it can be easily done by email. That lazy HR drone can send an email to the admin, another one to IT, another one to payroll etc.

By the way, this is one of the reasons HR is increasingly considered lazy and redundant. They need an entire task management system for something that it's supposed to be their job. Just use emails. It's the most efficient way.